# Does re-installing Ubuntu wipe out the previous LUKS encryption?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, encryption, luks

While installing Ubuntu 16.04, I had chosen to encrypt the installation. I want to remove it now.I have backed up all data and I donot care about any data loss whatsoever. Will re-installing Ubuntu (and choosing not to encrpyt while doing so) help? Or will it render the memory unusable. I have heard LUKS encryption uses headers, removing which causes problems. I am completely new to Ubuntu and don't know anything about these stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **backed up all data on unencrypted disc/partition/folder**. There is no problem with reinstalling Ubuntu. Choose whatever options you want. No problem if you **format the partitions used and do a fresh installation**.